# Time sheets to calculate time and send noifications

Tags: email, checkbox, calendar

I'm trying to make a time calculation sheet. Everything is fine until I want to add the reminder by appointment.
I can create reminders in another macro but in my main macro which has "function onEdit(e)" I can't authorise the macro to make changes to my diary.

Can you help me ? May I add something special to allow access to my calendar ?

Below details of error :

Autorisations requises : (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)
at creerrdv(creerrdv:2:31)
at checkboxButton_(macros:106:5)
at onEdit(macros:11:5)

```
type function onEdit(e) {
 if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. '
      + 'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.'
    );
  }
  try {
    ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL
    checkboxButton_(e);
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}

function checkboxButton_(e) {
  if (e.value === 'TRUE' && e.range.rowStart === 2  ) 
  {    e.range.uncheck();
const now = new Date();
const heure = new Date(now.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 9);
const feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const maxcellule = feuille.getRange('A2');
const lignesaisie = maxcellule.getValue()+1;
  
  if (e.range.columnStart === 2)  //le matin en arrivant
    {Macrosanstitre();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,e.range.columnStart+1,lignesaisie,7).setFontColor('ACCENT2');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,e.range.columnStart).setValue(heure); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,1).setValue(heure);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,1).setFontColor("black");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,2).setFontColor("black");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,3).setValue("12:10");

    const valeurp1 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie,3);
    const pausemidi=valeurp1.getValue().getHours()-9+valeurp1.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const moydur=feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,13);
    const durmoymidi=moydur.getValue().getHours()-9+moydur.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const valeurp2=pausemidi+durmoymidi;
    const valeurp21=Math.floor(valeurp2);
    valeurp22=Math.round((valeurp2-Math.floor(valeurp2))*60);
    valeurp22=(leftFillNum(valeurp22, 2)); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,4).setValue(valeurp21+":"+valeurp22);

    const valeur1 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie,2);
    const valeur2 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie,3);
    const valeur3 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie,4);
    const h1=valeur1.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur1.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h2=valeur2.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur2.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h3=valeur3.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur3.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h4=8.45-(h2-h1)+h3;
    const h41=Math.floor(h4);
    h42=Math.round((h4-Math.floor(h4))*60);
    const h5=h4-h3+h2-h1-0.25;
    h42=(leftFillNum(h42, 2));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,5).setValue(h41+":"+h42);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,6).setValue(h5);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie,7).setValue(h5-8.2);  } 
  
  if (e.range.columnStart === 3) //le matin en partant
    {Macrosanstitre();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,e.range.columnStart+1,lignesaisie-1,7).setFontColor('ACCENT2');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,e.range.columnStart).setValue(heure); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,3).setFontColor("black");

    const valeurp1 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,3);
    const pausemidi=valeurp1.getValue().getHours()-9+valeurp1.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const moydur=feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-2,13);
    const durmoymidi=moydur.getValue().getHours()-9+moydur.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const valeurp2=pausemidi+durmoymidi;
    const valeurp21=Math.floor(valeurp2);
    valeurp22=Math.round((valeurp2-Math.floor(valeurp2))*60);
    valeurp22=(leftFillNum(valeurp22, 2));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,4).setValue(valeurp21+":"+valeurp22);

    const h4=8.45-(h2-h1)+h33;
    const h41=Math.floor(h4);
    h42=Math.round((h4-Math.floor(h4))*60);
    h42=(leftFillNum(h42, 2));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,5).setValue(h41+":"+h42);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,6).setValue(h5);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,7).setValue(h5-8.2); 
    
    var start = new Date(feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,4).getValue()).getTime()- 1000 * 60 * 60 * 9
    var end = new Date(feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,4).getValue()).getTime()- 1000 * 60 * 60 * 9
    creerrdv('Retour boulot', new Date(start), new Date(end));}

  if (e.range.columnStart === 4) //laprém en arrivant
    {Macrosanstitre();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,e.range.columnStart+1,lignesaisie-1,7).setFontColor('ACCENT2');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,e.range.columnStart).setValue(heure); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,4).setFontColor("black");
    const valeur1 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,2);
    const valeur2 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,3);
    const valeur3 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,4);
    const h1=valeur1.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur1.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h2=valeur2.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur2.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h3=valeur3.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur3.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h4=8.45-(h2-h1)+h3;
    const h41=Math.floor(h4);
    h42=Math.round((h4-Math.floor(h4))*60);
    h42=(leftFillNum(h42, 2));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,5).setValue(h41+":"+h42);
    const event = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), h41, h42, 0);
    creerrdv('Départ boulot', new Date(event), new Date(event));  } 

  if (e.range.columnStart === 5) //aprém en partant
    {Macrosanstitre();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,e.range.columnStart+1,lignesaisie-1,7).setFontColor("black");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,e.range.columnStart).setValue(heure); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,5).setFontColor("black");
    const valeur1 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,2);
    const valeur2 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,3);
    const valeur3 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,4);
    const valeur4 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,5);
    const h1=valeur1.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur1.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h2=valeur2.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur2.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h3=valeur3.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur3.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h4=valeur4.getValue().getHours()+15+valeur4.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h5=h4-h3+h2-h1-0.25;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,6).setValue(h5);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,7).setValue(h5-8.2);  } 

  if (e.range.columnStart === 6) //pour maj
    {Macrosanstitre();
    const valeur1 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,2);
    const valeur2 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,3);
    const valeur3 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,4);
    const valeur4 = feuille.getRange(lignesaisie-1,5);
    const h1=valeur1.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur1.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h2=valeur2.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur2.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h3=valeur3.getValue().getHours()-9+valeur3.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h4=valeur4.getValue().getHours()+15+valeur4.getValue().getMinutes()/60;
    const h5=h4-h3+h2-h1-0.25;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,6).setValue(h5);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lignesaisie-1,7).setValue(h5-8.2);  } 
  
}
}


function Macrosanstitre() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:E1000').setNumberFormat('hh":"mm');
};

function leftFillNum(num, targetLength) {
  return num.toString().padStart(targetLength, "0");
};
```

PS: I use it on smartphone that's why I use checkboxes

Allow all
put it in a new macro
put my email id instead of defaultname

Comment: Perhaps I can show the prompt to accept... It's hidden by onedit () ?

Comment: Try to reduce your code to the absolute minmum required to reproduce the issue. There's a lot of (seemingly) irrelevant code. Made a bit worse by the fact that it's not English.

Comment: Ok I find something use installedOnEdit(e) instead of OnEdit(e) https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/58891b5caaf49ebfdb5f8dde4637d8e6